# FastAPI DB Context

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi

I think I am misunderstanding how dependency injection is used in FastAPI, specifically in the context of DB sessions.

My current set up is FastAPI, SqlAlchhemy & Alembic, although i am writing the raw SQL myself, pydantic etc, pretty straight forward.

I have basic CRUD routes which communicate directly to my repository layer and all is working. In these methods I am able to successfully use the DB dependency injection. See example code below:

**Dependencies**

```
def get_database(request: Request) -> Database:
    return request.app.state._db

def get_repository(Repo_type: Type[BaseRepository]) -> Callable:
    def get_repo(db: Database = Depends(get_database)) -> Type[BaseRepository]:
        return Repo_type(db)
    return get_repo
```

**Example GET by ID Route**

```
@router.get("/{id}/", response_model=TablePub, name="Get Table by id")
async def get_table_by_id(
    id: UUID, table_repo: TableRepository = Depends(get_repository(TableRepository))
) -> TableInDB:
    table = await table_repo.get_table_by_id(id=id)
    if not table:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail="No Table found with that id.")
    return table
```

**Corresponding Repository**

```
from databases import Database

class BaseRepository:
    def __init__(self, db: Database) -> None:
        self.db = db

class TableRepository(BaseRepository):

    async def get_table_by_id(self, *, id: UUID) -> TableInDB:
        table = await self.db.fetch_one(
            query=GET_TABLE_BY_ID_QUERY, 
            values={"id": id},
        )
        if not table:
            return None
        return TableInDB(**table)
```

Now I want to start doing some more complex operations and want to add a service layer to house all of the business logic.

What is the correct way to structure this so that i can reuse the repositories that i have already written? For example, i want to return all Sales for a Table, but i need to get the table number from the DB first before i can query the Sales Table. The route requires table_id to be passed in as a param -> service layer, where i fetch the table by ID (Using existing repo) -> from that object, get the table number, then do a request to an external API that requires the table number as a param.

What I have so far:

**Route**

```
@router.get("/{table_id}", response_model=SalesPub, name="Get Sale Entries by table id")
async def get_sales_by_table_id(
    table_id: UUID = Path(..., title="ID of the Table to get Sales Entries for")):
    response = await SalesService.get_sales_from_external_API(table_id=table_id)
    return response
```

**Service Layer 'SalesService'**

```
async def get_sales_from_external_API(
        table_id: UUID, 
        table_repo: TableRepository = Depends(get_repository(TableRepository))
        ) -> TableInDB:
        table_data = await table_repo.get_table_by_id(id=table_id)
        if table_data is None:
            logger.info(f"No table with id:{table_id} could not be found")
        table_number = table_data.number
        client_id = table_data.client_id
        
        sales = await salesGateway.call_external_API(table_number, client_id)
        return sales
```

The code brakes here `table_data = await table_repo.get_table_by_id(id=table_id)`

With an error `AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'get_table_by_id'`

What i don't understand is that the code is almost identical to the route method that can get the table by ID? The depends object `TableRepository` does have a `get_table_by_id` method. What is it that i'm doing incorrectly, and is this the best way to split up business logic from database actions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could have a `get_sales_service` function that has the required dependencies for creating the `SalesService` object. This function is then responsible for creating the object and assigning any dependencies to the service, so that `TableRepository` would be a local attribute of the class instead; `self.table_repository.get_table_by_id(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution to this, although i'm not sure if it is the best way.

The `Depends` Module only works on FastAPI routes and Dependencies. I was trying to use it on a regular function.

I needed to make the parameter `table_repo` an instance of `Depends`. and pass it in as a parameter to the external API call function.

```
@router.get("/table/{table_id}/", response_model=SalePub, name="Get Sales by table id")
    async def get_sales_by_table_id(
        table_id: UUID = Path(..., title="ID of the Table to get Sales Entries for"),
        table_repo: TableRepository = Depends(get_repository(TableRepository))):
        response = await get_sales_entries_from_pos(table_id=table_id, table_repo=table_repo)
        return response
```

The issue i am foreseeing is that if i have a large service that may need access to manny repos, i have to give that access on the router through Depends, which just seems a bit strange to me.